# How would I say something along the lines of "no kicks no glory", "no kickstart no glory"

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, idiom, sentence-translation, word-choice

The intention is to point out that there is no glory in starting your motorcycle with electricity. Starting up your engine by kicking your kickstart is the one true and pure way. I tried to figure it out by myself but not the easiest language to grasp in a blink of an eye.... Anyways I came up with the following: "sine calce nulla gloria". Is calce a kick or limestone? Beats me. Calcitro perhaps...? I'm so bewildered here. Please help me.